# How to convince Logcat to print only valuable data, and prevent vomiting useless spam logs

Tags: android, logcat

I want to make my logcat **to only print data which I would like to see** by calling

```
Log.i(...)
```

However, **logcat vomits EVERYTHING to my log**, and I'm **tired of filtering information with endless regex or by tags with every single time** I open a project.

Is there an **easy and reliable solution** for this?

For example:

```
2018-11-27 11:23:11.173 5084-5111/com.platinum D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7c2d1d4fa220: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x7c2d24e23bc0)
2018-11-27 11:23:11.471 5084-5084/com.platinum D/SQL Log: SQLiteQuery: SELECT * FROM DOG
2018-11-27 11:23:11.941 5084-5084/com.platinum W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@cb53553
2018-11-27 11:23:12.170 5084-5111/com.platinum D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7c2d1d4fa220: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x7c2d24e23bc0)
2018-11-27 11:23:12.198 5084-5111/com.platinum D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7c2d1d4fa220: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x7c2d24e23bc0)
2018-11-27 11:23:12.237 5084-5111/com.platinum D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7c2d1d4fa220: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x7c2d24e23bc0)
2018-11-27 11:23:12.287 5084-5111/com.platinum I/chatty: uid=10085(com.platinum) RenderThread identical 2 lines
2018-11-27 11:23:12.320 5084-5111/com.platinum D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7c2d1d4fa220: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x7c2d24e23bc0)
2018-11-27 11:23:12.675 5084-5111/com.platinum D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7c2d1d4fa220: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x7c2d24e23bc0)
```

I dont want to see such logs, I dont care about D/EGL_emulation. I would like to see only my logs, **which are belongs to my application's development.** I don't want to see any log from Android OS, or about any hardware functionings, or etc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where? Programmatically, in Android Studio, Eclipse,..? In Android Studio you could use the filter function...

Comment: Doesn't depend on the `TAG`? I also faced this issue and wrote a global tag to provide with my logs. Then I am filtering this tag (in case of Android Studio).

Comment: You can also select  show only selected application in dropdown

Comment: @Skemelio If you add this as an answer I'll accept.

Comment: @AdamVarhegyi Is it ok that I've just copied the comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't depend on the TAG?

I also faced this issue and **wrote a global tag** to provide with my logs.

Then I am filtering this tag (in case of Android Studio).

Answer (score 1):

You're unclear with **log levels**, it denotes effectiveness of logs. assume it like priority :

i.e.

0 - Verbose

1 - Debug

2 - Info

3 - Warn

4 - Error

5 - Assert

So, if you choose level **debug** means that it will print only *debug and higher logs*.

---

Start using tags in printing log if you want to filter your logcat.

**Ex.** `Log.i("your custom tag", "message")`

so, now you can filter with "**your custom tag**".

Answer (score 0):

filter by --> show only selected Application at right-top corner of logcat.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Android studio have awesome functionality filtering for log.

Example for if you want error log, you need `Log.e.` here are some examples and output image for it.

```
Log.e("my_tag","this is my error log");
Log.d("my_tag","this is my debug log");
Log.v("my_tag","this is my verbos log");
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes android studio messes up the filter.

Select the *device*, *app* and *log level* from the three dropdowns again and select **Show only selected application** from left dropdown too.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Additional to @JeelVankhede s answer you can also filter you log for a minimum log level to show:
[image]

If you e.g. use info here Log.d and Log.v won't be shown in your log anymore.